# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I'm working on a project that accesses the Exchange Server. Before I replaced the project to a server, everything went fine. But now I'm getting this error.

I don't find what I search in Google, so I hope someone of you can help me. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the specified assembly with your application or install it on your server.

Comment: you mean the dll that you install with EwsManagedApi32??

Comment: I mean `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` and all its dependencies.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio on the server. How can I do that? I thought by installing EWS Managed API, I don't have to do something else. :s

Comment: Installing Visual Studio is that an option?

Comment: See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/ddff58e8-9159-4de6-a4f7-62d4d64fa1d0/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: I copied the dll and xml file (which you get when installing EWS Managed API) to the bin-folder of my project. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact error, in VS2005, .Net 2 and 3.5

This is how I resolved it, and I had to find another solution, because this always failed and Windows would not let me register the DLL.

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web services\1.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
```

I went into the .Net Framework Configuration Wizard from Administration tools in Windows XP. Mine is .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration (version 2.0.50727.42).

I then went into Runtime Security Policy -> Increase Assembly Trust and pointed to the above DLL in my C drive. It was set to NO TRUST, for some reason! I changed it to FULL TRUST.

I then closed and re-opened my VS2005 project and everything is now working fine.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions but depends on which one solves your issue

solution 1- You need to add a Nuget Reference. In your project, right click "References" and click "manage Nuget packages" Then In the browse tab Search microsoft.Exchange.webservices and install :)

[image]

solution 2- You need to add a Reference. In your project, right click "References" and click "Add reference" Then go here and add **system.web.services** to your project.